# How to Merge file with Latest file in SVN

Tags: ios, svn, svnx

I'm using svn'X. i have one problem,i committed my latest code in svn. but xcode project not open when i check out and try to open because in committing time i did mistake. so, i check out previous version and did changes. its working fine. now i want to commit this working code in to svn. but before that i must update with latest version in svn. so, i did working copy update with latest version in svn. svn latest version already corrupted. because of that reason my working copy also corrupted.

again i did same, check out previous version and doing changes.

please tell me how to override or merge working copy with latest version copy in svn.

Answer (score 1):

1. check out the previous version.
2. do the changes you need.
3. copy the project files to another folder.
4. svn update to the latest version.
5. do the merge by yourself.
6. svn commit.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an svn conflict in your xcode project file which you can open using a text editor. To get to that file you right click on your `.xcodeproj` file and select "Show Package Content", the actual project file in the package is `project.pbxproj`.

You can [resolve the conflicts](http://ariejan.net/2007/07/04/how-to-resolve-subversion-conflicts/) by editing (as text) `project.pbxproj`, look for `=====` or `>>>>>`, the usual svn markers. Once you've done that you should be able to open your project as before, then commit your current version. XCode projects and xib files do not work together with version control very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this step
1) Copy the file to other place (Let say it safe folder)
2) download latest from SVN (just let the svn know you got the latest version)
3) Overwrite with the latest file from safe folder that you have modified into your work directory.

You should able to commit.